# What is the probability based on quantity and time

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gambling

Imagine a game where the player gets to choose the size of a ball they throw. The balls are sized by a diameter of 1,2,3 or 4 (choose your favorite units). They win by throwing the ball through an opening but the opening changes sizes over time. Given the following pattern over 1 second where the first value is size and the second value is time duration:

```
 [[3,0.2],
  [2,0.05],
  [4,0.2],
  [1,0.05],
  [3,0.2],
  [2,0.05],
  [1,0.2],
  [4,0.05],]
```

Here is an image to show the size of the hole over the duration of 1 second. How can you determine the probability of success depending on the ball chosen (assuming you have access to the hole and duration information)?
[holey ball game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBd1W.jpg)

I figured a simple way of determining probability for a chosen ball is to figure how long a hole, as large or larger than the ball, is exposed out of the second and that is the probability. So a ball of size 4 and a hole of size 4 (sum of.25 second duration), you would have a 25% chance of success, 3 would be hole size 3 and 4 so a 65% chance, 2: 75% and 1: 100%

Is this a correct assumption?